# Silence PHP cURL output in CLI

Tags: php, codeigniter, curl, command-line-interface

I am working on a **scraper** (in PHP) and use cURL to fetch pages. The script can be run both in CLI & browser.
This is my first time working with PHP on CLI and I was trying to make the screen pretty and have a nice data representation like scrape statistics show up.

I am able to generate the output the way I want it, well almost. But with every cURL request the server makes, it also outputs this the extra header information like this :

```
* About to connect() to imbd.com port 80 (#0)
*   Trying 123.111.222.333... * connected
> GET /categories/something.html HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:21.0) Gecko/20130401 Firefox/21.0
Host: imdb.com
Accept: */*

< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Server: nginx/1.4.1
< Date: Wed, 25 Dec 2013 02:17:06 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Connection: keep-alive
< Vary: Accept-Encoding
< X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.17
< Set-Cookie: mobileType=0%something; expires=Wed, 01-Jan-2014 02:17:06 GMT; path=/; domain=.imdb.com
< 
* Connection #0 to host imdb.com left intact
* Closing connection #0
...
Statistics
...
```

Function that uses cURL

```
    public function getHTML($url) 
    {
        $user_agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; U; zh-cn; rv:1.9.1.6) ...";
        
        $options = Array(
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,  
            CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => TRUE,  
            CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER => TRUE,
            CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 120,
            CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 120,
            CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
            CURLOPT_USERAGENT => $user_agent,
            CURLOPT_URL => $url,
        CURLOPT_VERBOSE => true,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
        );
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);
        $data = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        return $data;
    }
```

Now all I want to do is **hide this information from the CLI** as it does in the browser.
Had it been cli curl, i would use `-s` to shut it up. But I am unable to find an PHP alternative for this. Also, `CURLOPT_MUTE` is depreciated. All Google gave me was to set `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` true, which I already have.

Also I would like to know how can I **avoid setting any cookies** to avoid tracking.

If it helps in any way I am using

- OS : Ubuntu
- Software : PHP5.5
- Framework : CodeIgniter 3.0-dev
- Extension: cURL
- Interface : Command Line (Terminal)

Comment: Paste your code from script here.

Comment: @chanchal118 I have included the function that I call to fetch the html. I use it like `$html = $this->scrape->getHTML("http://imdb.com');`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Remove this.

```
CURLOPT_VERBOSE => true,
```

According to [php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php)

`Set value to`

> TRUE to output verbose information. Writes output to STDERR, or the file specified using CURLOPT_STDERR.